# Jquery - How to create an object based on all the divs in a class?

Tags: jquery, object, html, attr

On document ready, I am trying to create an object for all my div(s) in a class and assigned them based on the div's attribute 'id'. Here are my codes which doesn't work, I can't figure out.

```
<div class="supercolor" >                       
   <div class="colordiv" id="#111111" style="background-color:#111111;">&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="colordiv" id="#222222" style="background-color:#222222;" >&nbsp;</div>                
   <div class="colordiv" id="#333333" style="background-color:#333333;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

And in my script section.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('div.supercolor > div').each(function() {
      var color_object = { $(this).attr('id') : false }
   });
});
```

Thank you

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code, but you are not 'doing' anything with `color_object`. What are you trying to achieve? More details will help us to help you.

Comment: I think I should point out that your div IDs aren't valid.  An ID can't contain the # character, and it must start with a letter.

Comment: @Rob Cowie : I am trying to create a simple color picker based on div. I need to track if the user has click the div, by setting an object to each div. Upon clicked, the div's object will be set true. You may refer to this question I posted, this is the part 2 of the design. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932850/jquery-help-to-create-the-simplest-color-picker-ever)

Comment: @GordonM : Thanks, I will remove the # from ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function() {

    var divObjects = $("div.supercolor > div").map(function(val) {
        return new DivObject(this.id);
    }).get();

});

function DivObject(id) {
    this.id = id; 
    ...
}
```

This will take all your `<div>`'s and map them to div objects. You can pass in data from your individual `<div>` like the id and pass it to the constructor.

You have to call `.get()` to get out an array.

**[Edit]**

```
var testDiv = $.grep(divObjects, function(val) {
    val.id === "test"
})[0];
```

This code snippet may look more familiar though

```
var testDiv;
for (var i = 0, ii = divObjects.length; i < ii; i++) {
    var div = divObjects[i];
    if (div.id === "test") {
        testDiv = div;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry to ask this but I am very new to Jquery. How do I get the value of the object with the id#test? I tried divObjects.get('test').val() but that doesn't seems to work.

Comment: @mmk div objects is an array. You can either for loop over the array until you find the one with the id test or your can `$.grep` it.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is a good reason for you to store an array of 'DivObjects', I would consider changing your approach.

On page load, attach click handlers to each colour div toggle a 'selected' class on the div (and remove it from others).

```
$("div.supercolor > div").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('selected').siblings('.selected').removeClass('selected');
});
```

At any point you need to get the colour that has been selected (if any) select colour divs with 'selected' class, and pull it's id:

```
$("div.supercolor > div.selected").attr('id');
```

This may not be suitable in your situation, but it is simple and effective.

Comment: Actually storing array is not my intention in the first place. The reason I am asking this question is actually to track if user click and select it. Because upon click/selected, it will output a input checkbox with the div's id as checked. Then if the user click it again, it will become de-selected and html value for that div becomes nothing, removing the input check box. This is part of the question I asked earlier at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932850/jquery-help-to-create-the-simplest-color-picker-ever). Maybe you can take a look and suggest some ideas. Tx

Comment: I've added an answer to your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932850/jquery-help-to-create-the-simplest-color-picker-ever#5940131